# Regex supporting alphaNumeric and punctuation characters only

Tags: java, android, regex, validation

I'm working on an app that needs a password validation.

I should check if the password string contains only alphanumerical and puntionations, and at least it should be a combination of letters and numbers to pass.

Can someone help me and share a regex that will work for this validation?

Thanks

Comment: If you search on Google you will get a similar answer in  2 minutes. This is something very general.

Answer (score 2):

An idea with use of [lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
^(?=\D*\d)(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])\p{Graph}+$
```

Or as a Java string:

```
"^(?=\\D*\\d)(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])\\p{Graph}+$"
```

- `(?=\D*\d)` the first lookahead checks for a [digit](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)
- `(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])` the second for at least one alpha

From [`^` start to `$` end](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) [`\p{Graph}`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) [`+` one or more](https://www.google.at/#q=regex+quantifier).

- `\p{Graph}` consists of `[\p{Alnum}\p{Punct}]`
- `\p{Alnum}` alphanumeric characters `[A-Za-z0-9]`
- `\p{Punct}` one of `` !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~ ``

[See demo at regexplanet (Java)](http://fiddle.re/14x596)